# Issue with a Nested Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, infinite

I'm new to javascript and coding, in general.

I'm trying to draw a series of circles in randomized coordinates on a canvas, and I'm trying to determine the fillStyle for the group of circles depending on some other values, which aren't included here for simplicity. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting what appears to be an infinite loop here?

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 30; counter++) {
  var xCenter = 154;
  var yCenter = 270;
  var accuracyMod = (300 + 800) * 0.0013;

  var xMax = (xCenter + (100 - 50) * accuracyMod);
  var xMin = (xCenter - (100 - 50) * accuracyMod);
  var yMax = ((yCenter + (100 - 50) * accuracyMod)) - (100 - 50);
  var yMin = ((yCenter - (100 - 50) * accuracyMod)) - (100 - 50);

  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  console.log(randomIntFromInterval(xMin, xMax), (randomIntFromInterval(yMin, yMax)));

  var stroke = "color";
  var fill = "color";
  var intense = 85;
  for (var counter = 1; counter <= 7; counter++) {
    if (intense < 5) {
      stroke = "#fffdfc";
      fill = "#fffdfc";
    } else if (intense <= 20) {
      stroke = "#ffebd7";
      fill = "#ffebd7";
    } else if (intense <= 40) {
      stroke = "#ffae5f";
      fill = "#ffae5f";
    } else if (intense <= 60) {
      stroke = "#ff7402";
      fill = "#ff7402";
    } else if (intense <= 80) {
      stroke = "#e25610";
      fill = "#e25610";
    } else if (intense <= 95) {
      stroke = "#b84452";
      fill = "#b84452";
    } else {
      stroke = "#ac3f65";
      fill = "#ac3f65";
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, this is a perfect place for using `let` (in a modern JS environment) so each of your `counter` variables would be separately scoped if using `let`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is, because you're using `counter` as the iteration variable in both your outer and inner loops. The inner loop will leaver `counter` at `8`, every time. The outer loop test will never fail, so it will continue.

Use two separate counter variables. Also, indent your code to reflect its structure.